# MoveTowards cant be stopped

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have been making game in which you can go upstairs and when you press w `MoveTowards` will move you in the middle of stairs. Everything is working perfectly but i cant stop MoveTowards when animation stops and player is in middle of stairs. But `MoveTowards` still pulls me inside and player can´t move.

This is code that pulls player:

```
if(entered == 1 && klikw == 1)
{
     col.SetActive(true);
     Vector3 a = transform.position;
     Vector3 b = location.position;
     transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(a, b, speed);
     animator.SetFloat("whenhewalk", 1);
}
```

klikw is when player clicks w

Comment: Are you clearing `klikw` when the player releases w?

Answer (score 0):

- List item

float minDistance = 1.2f;

```
 void Update ()
 {
     if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, Player.transform.position) > minDistance ){
     transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, Player.transform.position, step);
     }
 }
```